# Install ubuntu on lenovo t540p without bricking

Tags: system-installation, lenovo, thinkpad

I have a new lenovo T540p. My plan is to swap out the hard drive for a 250gb SSD and install ubuntu on that. I am a bit wary since a few posts I have seen suggest that it is possible to brick this computer when installing ubuntu. However they also say that maybe with the newest firmware this is less of a problem. The solutions seem to differ between sites though. Has anyone installed ubuntu on this system recently and if so, what suggestions do you have for me and others for a clean installation?

References:

- [Google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hFTArhNbmpmEBRkwRg0DMbEzLBCl43F1HXoXtJ8cm0k/edit) with aggregated information and installation / usage report
- [Reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/1tymc4/lenovo_thinkpad_t540p_bricked_booting_linux/) about the bricking problem
- [Lenovo forum entry](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/T540p-BIOS-reliably-bricks-when-installing-Linux/td-p/1390853) about the bricking problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead with the install and there were no problems. With Windows 7 pre-installed the BIOS was already configured as suggested by the links in my earlier post. Switching out the hard drive and then installing 14.04 was pretty straight forward.

Comment: I was also a little bit scared. The bricking issue seems to be resolved with the newest firmware version. I did not take any complicated steps while installing and I am currently writing using my T540p ;) I will try to dig up the resources and add them here.